# XCode 6 invalid(ated) distribution provisioning profile after upload to appstore

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I noticed that if I change the "Capabilities" (Entitlements) in XCode6, it invalidates the AppID, which in turn invalidates the dependent Developer/Distributions Provisioning Profiles. I know those can be either regenerated by XCode automatically - or by me manually, no problem so far.

But I'm wondering what if I upload a version to the Appstore (and it passes the auto-verification), what would happen if I continue work and need more Entitlements? That would invalidate the Provisioning Profiles...

Would that affect the already uploaded app (which might be in the review-queue or being reviewed) - or even a released version? ... or can I "edit/regenerate", or even "delete and create a new" Distribution Provisioning Profile - without any effect on the already uploaded version?

Answer (score 1):

When you activate entitlements for an appId the mobileProvision is invalidated because you need to regenerate it so that it includes those entitlement.
For exemple if you activate push but keep on signing your app with an old profile it will never request Apple for a push Token.

That said the mobile provision is used in combination with your Developer/Distribution Profile at the time you build and sign your app. Changing or deleting on of those afterward has no effect on apps either in production or waiting for review (hopefully since it expires once a year :))